# Matlab Simulink Simulation Time

Tags: matlab, loops, simulink, locked, phase

I am using Simulink from Matlab. When plotting anything the Simulation Step Time is extremely slow. How can I change the step time in settings. I have tried a lot but I don't understand the settings pretty much.

[image: simulation time]

**Update:**
Phase Locked Loop

[image: pll]

Answer (score 1):

The speed of simulation depends on alot things including what sort of calculation is it making, adding user defined MATLAB function can slow it down alot. in order to change your sampling time to much higher one put all of your model in one subsystem and add a [trigger](http://de.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/trigger.html) port inside the subsystem and connect a [pulse generater](http://de.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/pulsegenerator.html) to the input of the trigger outside the subsystem, dont forget to change all your block from continous to discrete with inherited sampling time.use a bigger sampling time in the pulse generator this might speed up the simulation

Comment: My simulink model is a simple phase locked loop system. The idea is I want the stepping time to be like 0.5 sec, because the time T in the image steps too slow. Of course 0 at the beginning and then 0.0027 and 0.0051 and so on. I want it to be 0 -> 0.5 -> 1 -> 1.5 and so or  anything similar that can make the plotting faster

Comment: The time you are seeing is not your sampling time but the simulation time , there is a huge difference between them . can you share screenshot of your model ?